# Interaction Studio (Personalization) Event API

Tags: interaction-studio, evergage

does anybody know how interactions can be sent via the Event API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/personalization/guide/event-api-requests.html)
I can't construct the request in a way that the system understands what catalog object has been viewed. The above page doesn't have any example on the interaction part, and from [here] https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/personalization/guide/event-options-salesforceinteractions.html i can't construct the request. I want to send a CatalogObjectInteraction

This is not working:

```
{
    "action": "View Catalog Object",
    "source": {
        "channel": "Server",
        "pageType": "Article",
        "url": "https://example.com/how-does-the-api-work",
        "urlReferrer": "https://example.com",
        "operatingSystem": "Windows",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "clientIp": "10.10.10.10"
    },
    "user": {
        "id": "123456789"
    },
    "interaction": {
        "name": "ViewCatalogObject",
        "catalogObject": {
            "id": "how-does-the-api-work",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "How does the API work?",
                "url": "https://example.com/how-does-the-api-work"
            },
            "type": "Article",
            "relatedCatalogObjects": {
                "Category": [
                    "howto"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gives the response:

```
[Event was missing core field: userId (ID of current user or email address)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out based on this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pers_identity_event_api_about.htm&type=5
i've created a new identity type that remains the same for the visitors and use it in the api as attribute